# Local Drupal issue

Tags: virtual-machine

Receiving the following on my local machine. Any suggestions?

Warning: include(/app/drupal/vendor/composer/../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/drupal/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444 Call Stack: 0.2061 409760 1. {main}() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:0 0.2147 533832 2. spl_autoload_call() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:16 0.2147 533888 3. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:16 0.2147 533888 4. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /app/drupal/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322 Warning: include(): Failed opening '/app/drupal/vendor/composer/../../docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php' for inclusion (include_path='/app/drupal/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/app/drupal/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/app/drupal/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/app/drupal/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /app/drupal/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444 Call Stack: 0.2061 409760 1. {main}() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:0 0.2147 533832 2. spl_autoload_call() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:16 0.2147 533888 3. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:16 0.2147 533888 4. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /app/drupal/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /app/drupal/docroot/index.php on line 16 Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /app/drupal/docroot/index.php on line 16 Call Stack: 0.2061 409760 1. {main}() /app/drupal/docroot/index.php:0

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The site settings are located on `web/sites/default/settings.php` or `docroot/sites/default/settings.php` depending on your project scaffolding. The most important setting on this file is the database connection.

```
/**
 * Database configuration.
 */
$databases = [
  'default' =>
    [
      'default' =>
        [
          'database' => 'DB_NAME',
          'username' => 'DB_USERNAME',
          'password' => 'DB_APSSWORD',
          'host' => 'DB_HOST',
          'port' => 'DB_PORT',
          'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
        ],
    ],
];
```

To check all the settings see [the repo](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.x/sites/default/default.settings.php).

For more information on how to setup your environment and install Drupal check [the official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm going to venture myself and state that you have one of the following problems:

1. You haven't run `composer install` at your codebase root (from your post should be */app/drupal/*) or has exited with an error code.
2. You (I mean your webserver process) don't have permission to access either `core` directory or any of it's content. This can happen if yo run `composer install` as root (don't do sudo!).
3. And last but not least check your VM (you just tagged this as VM related) shared folders, meaning that if you don't map your entire codebase from your local to the VM you can found yourself with missing files errors like the one posted.

For future questions you need to come up with more than just pasting your terminal output. Happy coding!